# ActionBar Sherlock + MapView. Action Bar is not showing up.

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I created RoboSherlockMapActivity.java

```
import roboguice.RoboGuice;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnActivityResultEvent;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnConfigurationChangedEvent;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnContentChangedEvent;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnCreateEvent;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnDestroyEvent;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnNewIntentEvent;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnPauseEvent;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnRestartEvent;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnResumeEvent;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnStartEvent;
import roboguice.activity.event.OnStopEvent;
import roboguice.event.EventManager;
import roboguice.inject.ContentViewListener;
import roboguice.inject.RoboInjector;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class RoboSherlockMapActivity extends MapActivity{

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
    }

    protected EventManager eventManager;

    @Inject ContentViewListener ignored; // BUG find a better place to put this

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final RoboInjector injector = RoboGuice.getInjector(this);
        eventManager = injector.getInstance(EventManager.class);
        injector.injectMembersWithoutViews(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        eventManager.fire(new OnCreateEvent(savedInstanceState));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        eventManager.fire(new OnRestartEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        eventManager.fire(new OnStartEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        eventManager.fire(new OnResumeEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        eventManager.fire(new OnPauseEvent());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent( Intent intent ) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        eventManager.fire(new OnNewIntentEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        try {
            eventManager.fire(new OnStopEvent());
        } finally {
            super.onStop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        try {
            eventManager.fire(new OnDestroyEvent());
        } finally {
            try {
                RoboGuice.destroyInjector(this);
            } finally {
                super.onDestroy();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        final Configuration currentConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        eventManager.fire(new OnConfigurationChangedEvent(currentConfig, newConfig));
    }

    @Override
    public void onContentChanged() {
        super.onContentChanged();
        RoboGuice.getInjector(this).injectViewMembers(this);
        eventManager.fire(new OnContentChangedEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        eventManager.fire(new OnActivityResultEvent(requestCode, resultCode, data));
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

I inherited this and not MapActivity. Still the Action bar Sherlock doesn't show up. What might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `ActionBarSherlock` with `MapActivity` you have to extend your `Activity` class from 
`com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockMapActivity` which you can download from [ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps).

This class is a plugin for ActionBarSherlock to support `MapActivity` link to mentioned github project you can also find in [ActionBarSherlock download section](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html).

Comment: Could you post also your AndroidManifest.xml, and layout file? I have just check above solution on my project and it is working so there must be some mistake in other place.

Comment: I had a done a terrible mistake on my AndroidManifest.xml. Bloody dumb of me. Thanks nonetheless!